# Sync offline files over VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, sync

I did some experiments with folders available offline with Windows 10 and this is what I understand:

- An user working from home can set a folder as available offline so opening and saving a file while at home will be faster than it would be via VPN (good)
- When the user is back in the office the local files and the network drive will be synchronized (good)
- If the users works from home for a month, then nothing is synchronized for a month (bad)

I was not able to get the files to synchronize via the slow VPN connection.

This makes the offline folders useful only in the rare cases when an user is out of the office for very short periods.

Is it possible to setup the offline folders to synchronize via VPN? Even if it is slow and it takes the whole night, it is still faster than waiting for a month.

Comment: have you looked in GPEdit.msc?  There are policies under both Comp & User configuration.  You want most under Computer Config -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Offline Files.  There's background sync and configuring Slow Link Mode & Speed

Comment: @TG2 I would mark this as the correct answer. I can't use/test it now, because I'm at home and I can't activate the offline availability over VPN. I tried to decrease the slow link speed down to 1, but I still can't see the `Always available offline` item. Do you know if there is a way to do the first synchronization over VPN?

Comment: found this link.. it has a lot of good info... https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/04/windows-7-offline-files-survival-guide/  (as to the first time sync -- other than the link not really, I've had too many bad experiences with roaming profiles, and off line files.. I generally break myself out of the company mold and redirect my files to local only.  I find Google Drive and Dropbox the best alternatives, plus they can exist as folders off a parent, rather than taking a higher order folder like "C:\Users\UserX" which wreaks havoc with things like PST files when they generally are huge.